# Math.floor en Javascript arroja un NaN

Tags: javascript, math

El siguiente código debería convertir un número entero entre 0 y 99 entrado por el usuario y devolver el mismo numeral en español.

```js
function escribir(){

    let entero = Number(document.getElementById("entero").value);
    let unidades, decenas, numeralDecenas, numeralUnidades;
    
    decenas = Math.floor(entero/10);
    unidades = entero - (decenas * 10);
    
    switch (decenas){
        case 0:
            switch (entero){
                case 0:
                    numeralDecenas = ""
                    numeralUnidades = "cero";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    numeralDecenas = ""
                    numeralUnidades = "uno";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    numeralDecenas = ""
                    numeralUnidades = "dos";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    numeralDecenas = ""
                    numeralUnidades = "tres";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    numeralDecenas = ""
                    numeralUnidades = "cuatro";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    numeralDecenas = ""
                    numeralUnidades = "cinco";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    numeralDecenas = ""
                    numeralUnidades = "seis";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    numeralDecenas = ""
                    numeralUnidades = "siete";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    numeralDecenas = ""
                    numeralUnidades = "ocho";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    numeralDecenas = ""
                    numeralUnidades = "nueve";          
            } 
            break;  
        case 1:
            switch (entero){
                case 0:
                    numeralDecenas = ""
                    numeralUnidades = "diez";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    numeralDecenas = ""
                    numeralUnidades = "once";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    numeralDecenas = ""
                    numeralUnidades = "doce";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    numeralDecenas = ""
                    numeralUnidades = "trece";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    numeralDecenas = ""
                    numeralUnidades = "catorce";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    numeralDecenas = ""
                    numeralUnidades = "quince";
                    break;
                case 6:
                    numeralDecenas = "dieci";
                    numeralUnidades = "séis";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    numeralDecenas = "dieci";
                    numeralUnidades = "siete";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    numeralDecenas = "dieci";
                    numeralUnidades = "ocho";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    numeralDecenas = "dieci";
                    numeralUnidades = "nueve";
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            switch (entero){
                case 0:
                    numeralUnidades = "veinte";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    numeralDecenas = "veinti";
                    numeralUnidades = "uno";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    numeralDecenas = "veinti";
                    numeralUnidades = "dós";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    numeralDecenas = "veinti";
                    numeralUnidades = "trés";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    numeralDecenas = "veinti";
                    numeralUnidades = "cuatro";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    numeralDecenas = "veinti";
                    numeralUnidades = "cinco";
                    break;  
                case 6:
                    numeralDecenas = "veinti";
                    numeralUnidades = "séis";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    numeralDecenas = "veinti";
                    numeralUnidades = "siete";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    numeralDecenas = "veinti";
                    numeralUnidades = "ocho";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    numeralDecenas = "veinti";
                    numeralUnidades = "nueve";
                    break;  
            }
            break;
        case 3:
            switch (entero){
                case 0:
                    numeralUnidades = "treinta";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    numeralDecenas = "treinta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "uno";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    numeralDecenas = "treinta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "dós";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    numeralDecenas = "treinta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "trés";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    numeralDecenas = "treinta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "cuatro";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    numeralDecenas = "treinta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "cinco";
                    break;  
                case 6:
                    numeralDecenas = "treinta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "séis";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    numeralDecenas = "treinta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "siete";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    numeralDecenas = "treinta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "ocho";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    numeralDecenas = "treinta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "nueve";
                    break;  
            }
            break;
        case 4:
            switch (entero){
                case 0:
                    numeralUnidades = "cuarenta";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    numeralDecenas = "cuarenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "uno";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    numeralDecenas = "cuarenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "dós";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    numeralDecenas = "cuarenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "trés";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    numeralDecenas = "cuarenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "cuatro";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    numeralDecenas = "cuarenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "cinco";
                    break;  
                case 6:
                    numeralDecenas = "cuarenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "séis";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    numeralDecenas = "cuarenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "siete";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    numeralDecenas = "cuarenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "ocho";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    numeralDecenas = "cuarenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "nueve";
                    break;  
            }
            break;
        case 5:
            switch (entero){
                case 0:
                    numeralUnidades = "cincuenta";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    numeralDecenas = "cincuenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "uno";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    numeralDecenas = "cincuenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "dós";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    numeralDecenas = "cincuenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "trés";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    numeralDecenas = "cincuenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "cuatro";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    numeralDecenas = "cincuenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "cinco";
                    break;  
                case 6:
                    numeralDecenas = "cincuenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "séis";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    numeralDecenas = "cincuenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "siete";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    numeralDecenas = "cincuenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "ocho";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    numeralDecenas = "cincuenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "nueve";
                    break;  
            }
            break;
        case 6:
            switch (entero){
                case 0:
                    numeralUnidades = "sesenta";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    numeralDecenas = "sesenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "uno";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    numeralDecenas = "sesenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "dós";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    numeralDecenas = "sesenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "trés";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    numeralDecenas = "sesenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "cuatro";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    numeralDecenas = "sesenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "cinco";
                    break;  
                case 6:
                    numeralDecenas = "sesenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "séis";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    numeralDecenas = "sesenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "siete";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    numeralDecenas = "sesenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "ocho";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    numeralDecenas = "sesenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "nueve";
                    break;  
            }
            break;
        case 7:
            switch (entero){
                case 0:
                    numeralUnidades = "setenta";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    numeralDecenas = "setenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "uno";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    numeralDecenas = "setenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "dós";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    numeralDecenas = "setenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "trés";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    numeralDecenas = "setenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "cuatro";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    numeralDecenas = "setenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "cinco";
                    break;  
                case 6:
                    numeralDecenas = "setenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "séis";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    numeralDecenas = "setenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "siete";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    numeralDecenas = "setenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "ocho";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    numeralDecenas = "setenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "nueve";
                    break;  
            }
            break;
        case 8:
            switch (entero){
                case 0:
                    numeralUnidades = "ochenta";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    numeralDecenas = "ochenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "uno";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    numeralDecenas = "ochenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "dós";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    numeralDecenas = "ochenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "trés";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    numeralDecenas = "ochenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "cuatro";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    numeralDecenas = "ochenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "cinco";
                    break;  
                case 6:
                    numeralDecenas = "ochenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "séis";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    numeralDecenas = "ochenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "siete";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    numeralDecenas = "ochenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "ocho";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    numeralDecenas = "ochenta y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "nueve";
                    break;  
            }
            break;
        case 9:
            switch (entero){
                case 0:
                    numeralUnidades = "noventa";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    numeralDecenas = "noventa y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "uno";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    numeralDecenas = "noventa y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "dós";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    numeralDecenas = "noventa y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "trés";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    numeralDecenas = "noventa y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "cuatro";
                    break;
                case 5:
                    numeralDecenas = "noventa y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "cinco";
                    break;  
                case 6:
                    numeralDecenas = "noventa y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "séis";
                    break;
                case 7:
                    numeralDecenas = "noventa y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "siete";
                    break;
                case 8:
                    numeralDecenas = "noventa y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "ocho";
                    break;
                case 9:
                    numeralDecenas = "noventa y ";
                    numeralUnidades = "nueve";
                    break;  
            }
        }
        

    document.getElementById("numeral").innerHTML = numeralDecenas + numeralUnidades;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ESCRIBIR NUMERALES</title>
</head>
<body>

    <input id="entero" type="text" size="31" placeholder="Introduce un número entero entre 0 y 99">
    <input type="button" onclick="escribir()" value="Los numerales en español se escriben así:">

    <p id="numeral"></p>
    <p id="unidades"></p>
    <p id="decenas"></p>

    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
   
</body>
</html>
```

Entre el 0 y el 9 funciona correctamente, pero me da un NaN partir de las decenas. Es por eso que en un principio he pensado que el error estaba aquí :`decenas = Math.floor(entero/10);`, pero he hecho una prueba muy sencilla con ese mismo método y no parece ser ese el problema...

Mis dudas son:

- Si el método Math.floor() devuelve el entero sin decimales, ¿por qué está fallando aquí?
- Si Math.floor() no es el más adecuado, ¿qué otro método se podría usar?

Gracias!

Comment: Puede ser porque haces `switch (entero){` donde deberías hacer `switch (unidades){`

Comment: Por otra parte, si creas una lista con todos los números en español, de modo que cada uno coincida con su índice, solo tendrás que buscar ese índice para obtener el texto correspondiente...

Comment: @FranciscoJavier, ¿te refieres a escribir uno a uno todos los numerales? Esa sería casi usar la fuerza bruta, la idea del ejercicio que nos proponen es el de usar los `switch` y de separar las decenas de las unidades, de ahí mis variables *decenas* y *unidades*, respectivamente.
Voy a probar lo que propones en tu primer comentario.

Comment: Si tienes obligación de usar los `switch` no digo nada, pero es la misma fuerza bruta, ¿no crees? O los escribes en los `switch` o lo haces en una lista... Pero la lista aligera mucho el código.

Comment: @FranciscoJavier, es un ejercicio para trabajar el `switch`, sí. Lo de la fuerza bruta pues en realidad también, aunque claro, hechas las decenas del 30, hechas del resto… 
Gracias por el tip de cambiar la variable del switch anidado… obviamente era eso!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

También olvidaste agregar la linea:

```
numeralDecenas = "";
```

En todos los

```
case 0:
    numeralUnidades = "veinte";
    break;
```

A partir de decimal 2, es decir en veinte, treinta, etc. Para que no arroje Undefined. Con su respectivo ";" que también faltan en algunos casos al principio.

Answer (score 1):

Optimice tu código y solucioné el error que presentabas.

En algunos casos no hay que usar `switch()` ya que lo único que estarías haciendo, es escribir más líneas de código de las que deberías.

```js
function escribir() {

  var ELEMENT_ENTERO = document.getElementById("entero"),
    ELEMENT_NUMERAL = document.getElementById("numeral"),
    ELEMENT_DECENAS = document.getElementById("decenas"),
    ELEMENT_UNIDADES = document.getElementById("unidades");

  var ENTERO = ELEMENT_ENTERO.value;

  var MATH_DECENAS = Math.floor(ENTERO / 10);

  var NUMERAL_UNIDADES = ENTERO > 9 ? ENTERO.replace(/^(\d)/, "") : ENTERO;

  var TRANSFORM_NUMBER = {
    "0": {
      "0": "Cero",
      "1": "Uno",
      "2": "Dos",
      "3": "Tres",
      "4": "Cuatro",
      "5": "Cinco",
      "6": "Seis",
      "7": "Siete",
      "8": "Ocho",
      "9": "Nueve",
    },
    "1": {
      "10": "Diez",
      "11": "Once",
      "12": "Doce",
      "13": "Trece",
      "14": "Catorce",
      "15": "Quince",
      "16": "Dieciséis",
      "17": "Diecisiete",
      "18": "Dieciocho",
      "19": "Diecinueve",
    },
  };

  var ESCRITURA_NUMERO = TRANSFORM_NUMBER[MATH_DECENAS][ENTERO];

  ELEMENT_NUMERAL.innerHTML = "SE ESCRIBE: " + ESCRITURA_NUMERO;

  ELEMENT_DECENAS.innerHTML = "DECENAS: " + (MATH_DECENAS == 0 ? "No hay decenas" : MATH_DECENAS);

  ELEMENT_UNIDADES.innerHTML = "UNIDADES: " + NUMERAL_UNIDADES;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>ESCRIBIR NUMERALES</title>
</head>

<body>

  <input id="entero" type="text" placeholder="Introduce un número entero entre 0 y 19">
  <input type="button" onclick="escribir()" value="Los numerales en español se escriben así:">

  <p id="numeral"></p>
  <p id="decenas"></p>
  <p id="unidades"></p>

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Espero haberte ayudado!

Comment: Gracias Daniel, por la ayuda Daniel. Pero ese código solo soluciona los primeros 20 números y el ejercicio es del 0 al 99, y además, como explicaba, es para practicar el switch ;)

Answer (score 0):

Los errores que me planteaba mi código quedan resumidos en estas dos correcciones:

1. `switch (entero)` por `switch (unidades)`
2. Añadir `numeralDecenas = "";` a todos los `case 0`

Gracias por la ayuda.